# Review completed, but answer not deleted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues

I thought 6 *recommend deletions* removed posts. Something wrong?

https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/7632

After the review, I went ahead and downvoted it to balance the 1 positive score it had, which was what denied me the permission to actually vote to delete. But I don't think it worked. Isn't the automatic deletion supposed to happen here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145292/369802) six recommend deletion votes will only automatically delete a post if it has a score of zero or less. So, if it was at 1 when you submitted your review, it wouldn't be deleted.

> Yes, a sufficient number of delete recommendations (currently 6 on most sites, 4 on Stack Overflow) will cause the post to be deleted immediately, provided it has zero or negative score. (If it has a positive score, it will raise an automatic moderator flag instead.)

I guess it's up to the mods to delete this now, although I cast a vote putting it at -1 and casting a delete vote.  I also flagged it as very low quality again.

This is why I always take the time to click the 'link' button on the review page, open the post in a new tab and cast a downvote before I'm going to vote to delete a post. Just a tip for if you want to prevent this next time.